# AWS Request signing in IntelliJ/PhpStorm .http request file

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, httprequest, phpstorm

I'm using the cool feature in PhpStorm where you can make `.http` files to define HTTP requests. But I am having trouble getting AWS Request signing to work. I've written this pre-request script to sign the request but the error message I get back is:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.

Obviously, this is super hard to debug because the signature is either absolutely 100% correct or totally completely wrong. I don't know if my script is close with 1 line wrong or if my entire approach is off.

I followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/create-signed-request.html

And this is what I produced...

```js
const region = "eu-west-2";
const service = "execute-api";

const date = new Date;

const dateTimeInAmazonsFormat = (date.toISOString()).replace(/[:-]*/g, '').replace(/\.\d*/, '');

request.variables.set("XAmzDate", dateTimeInAmazonsFormat)

const eightDigitDate = dateTimeInAmazonsFormat.substr(0,8);

const CanonicalHeaders =
    "content-type:application/json\n" +
    "host:integration.example.com\n" +
    "x-amz-date:" + dateTimeInAmazonsFormat + "\n";

const CanonicalRequest = "POST\n" + // HTTPMethod
    "/clients/reader" + "\n" + // CanonicalUri
    "\n" + // CanonicalQueryString
    CanonicalHeaders + "\n" + // CanonicalHeaders
    "content-type;host;x-amz-date\n"  + // SignedHeaders
    crypto.sha256().updateWithText(request.body.tryGetSubstituted()).digest().toHex();

const HashedCanonicalRequest = crypto.sha256().updateWithText(CanonicalRequest).digest().toHex();

const StringToSign = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n" +
    dateTimeInAmazonsFormat + "\n" +
    eightDigitDate + "/" + region + "/" + service + "/aws4_request\n" +
    HashedCanonicalRequest;

const kDate = crypto.hmac.sha256()
    .withTextSecret("AWS4" + request.environment.get("AWSSecretKey"))
    .updateWithText(eightDigitDate)
    .digest().toHex();

const kRegion = crypto.hmac.sha256()
    .withTextSecret(kDate)
    .updateWithText(region)
    .digest().toHex();

const kService = crypto.hmac.sha256()
    .withTextSecret(kRegion)
    .updateWithText(service)
    .digest().toHex();

const kSigning = crypto.hmac.sha256()
    .withTextSecret(kService)
    .updateWithText("aws4_request")
    .digest().toHex();

const signature = crypto.hmac.sha256()
    .withTextSecret(kSigning)
    .updateWithText(StringToSign)
    .digest().toHex();

const authorization = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 " +
    "Credential=" + request.environment.get("AWSAccessKey") + "/" + eightDigitDate + "/" + region + "/" + service + "/aws4_request, " +
    "SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, " +
    "Signature=" + signature;

request.variables.set("Authorization", authorization)
```

I appreciate most people don't write the signing themselves they just import in a library but I don't think that's an option with `.http` files in PhpStorm. Any guidance from someone whose got it working would be fantastic or if someone knows of an open source library written in JavaScript that I could reference, I'd be very grateful.